# Exclude Class/Methods while using FxcopIntegrator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, fxcop

While integrating FxCop with visual studio, i found [FxCop Integrator](
http://fxcopintegrator.codeplex.com)

Though this seems to be a very good tool (which almost eliminates the need to run FxCop independently), i could not find way to exclude classes or methods while doing CodeAnalysis.

Does FxcopIntegrator support that in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using it with an FxCop project file that is pre-configured with your class and method exclusions, as described at http://fxcopintegrator.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Analyze%20With%20FxCop%20Project%20File?

Comment: thanks for the update. I followed steps mentioned in the link  (i.e. created CodeAnalysis folder at solution root and added fxCop project in the folder) but i don't see option 'CodeAnalysis with FxCop' option when i right click on the solution. I even tried to install latest package from CodePlex but it doesn't work. Anything i am missing?

Comment: It seems, this can be done by this way : Right Click on solution -> More tasks... -> Inspect solution. As usual, documentation is not updated for the latest changes :)